# eyeSeparation property in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, renderer, stereo-3d

I am trying to change the value of `eyeSeparation` in A-Frame coding. How can I do it?

Referring to the documents of three.js:

```
effect = new THREE.StereoEffect( renderer );
effect.eyeSeparation = 0;
```

This would result in no difference in rendering between the left and right images. I guess that the documents of https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/camera.html
would give the way for changing `eyeSeparation` settings, but I cannot find the way to do it.

Best,

Shunji

Answer (score 0):

Eye separation is provided by the WebVR / WebXR APIs and user configured through the headset via software (e.g; oculus settings) or hardware (Rift slider or Vive dial). It’s not something that content can control. StereoEffect is not used by A-Frame or THREE VR path. It’s an old  module that predates WebVR

Comment: I am using Oculus go, and execute https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/ . It works well indeed. Moreover, I am trying to obtain full screen VR images in which the right and left images are identical (no binocular difference) by Oculus go, in order to investigate depth perception depending on binocular difference. Do you have any idea?